# getting error while trying to make a new post in pelican

Tags: python, pelican

Hi I made a post yesterday with title "Oi" now I am trying to make new post with a different title, but its trying to mess with the old one and I am

getting this warning and error message:

```
WARNING: There are 2 variants of "oi" with lang en
WARNING: Development/web_projects/weeklyUpdate/content/2015_06_06_oi.md
WARNING: Development/web_projects/weeklyUpdate/content/2015_06_07_oi.md
CRITICAL: File Development/web_projects/weeklyUpdate/output/oi.html is to be overwritten
```

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have your two posts in your content directory,

```
content/
├── post1.md
└── post2.md
```

with the same title but different authors/contents.

**post1.md**

```
Title: Oi
Author: Dr. Jekyll
Date: 2015-07-15 10:30
Category: StackOverflow
Tags: pelican

"Well, I tell you so again," continued the lawyer. "I have been
learning something of young Hyde."

The large handsome face of Dr. Jekyll grew pale to the very lips,
and there came a blackness about his eyes. "I do not care to hear
more," said he. "This is a matter I thought we had agreed to drop."
```

**post2.md**

```
Title: Oi
Author: Mr. Hyde
Date: 2015-07-15 10:20
Category: StackOverflow
Tags: pelican

"We have common friends," said Mr. Utterson.

"Common friends?" echoed Mr. Hyde, a little hoarsely. "Who are
they?"

"Jekyll, for instance," said the lawyer.
```

Because Pelican "slugifies" these posts using the post title, it causes a name conflict, which you're seeing.

The solution is to add the `Slug: my-slug-line` metadata to each post, to force the post to render to `my-slug-line.html`. In our example:

**post1.md**

```
Title: Oi
Author: Dr. Jekyll
Date: 2015-07-15 10:30
Category: StackOverflow
Tags: pelican
Slug: oi-dr-jekyll

"Well, I tell you so again," continued the lawyer. "I have been
learning something of young Hyde."

The large handsome face of Dr. Jekyll grew pale to the very lips,
and there came a blackness about his eyes. "I do not care to hear
more," said he. "This is a matter I thought we had agreed to drop."
```

**post2.md**

```
Title: Oi
Author: Mr. Hyde
Date: 2015-07-15 10:20
Category: StackOverflow
Tags: pelican
Slug: oi-mr-hyde

"We have common friends," said Mr. Utterson.

"Common friends?" echoed Mr. Hyde, a little hoarsely. "Who are
they?"

"Jekyll, for instance," said the lawyer.
```

This will output the first post by Dr. Jekyll into `oi-dr-jekyll.html`, and the second post by Mr. Hyde into `oi-mr-hyde.html`.

The `Slug:` metadata is optional, so you don't **have** to do this unless you run into naming conflicts. But it can come in handy sometimes.

**Also note:**

If you want to do the same thing for non-blog or "static" pages, like an "About Me" page written in Markdown, you can use the `save_as: my_page.html` metadata to force the Markdown to be rendered out to `my_page.html`, whatever the page title happens to be.

Comment: thanks for the save_as tip, that is very useful. Before you replied I did got answer about explicitly specifying the slug in metadata which helped. Nowadays I am struggling how to make post segragated week wise , like a month has 4 weeks but their seem no plugin either for this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok - if you want to open a new question, I'll give it a shot. I've done a bit of date processing in Jinja, and you could do that on the template level.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that both posts have the same slug (the local part of the post URL). It can be explicitly set via the "slug" metadata field in your post, or generated from date, title, etc.). In your case, both posts have the same URL "/oi.html" and pelican refuses to overwrite the first generated file with the content of the second post.

Comment: But I didn't added any slug to the second post

Comment: Then do it. ;) The error message says "CRITICAL: .../output/oi.html is to be overwritten" means, that two posts want to be written to the same output file. So define the output location explicitly by defining the slug in the header of your posts. If that works, you can find "better" ways to generate the slug from your posts metadata, if you want that. Be explicit at first.